# which test to do first?

Tags: normal-distribution, anova, autocorrelation, multicollinearity, heteroscedasticity

I have a dataset that has 4 Columns as x axis. I want to check the data for:
Autocorrelation,
Multicolinearity,
Heteroscedasticity and
Normality,
In what order should ı perform the tests?
And ıf my data turns out to be not normal, can I still perform ANOVA?

Comment: Don't do tests.  Fit the model, look at the residuals.

Comment: shouldn't I perform anova before I use any regression model?

Comment: Anova is technically a regression model.  I would suggest not using a hypothesis test to assess the assumptions.